# Saving form element to a text file on server

Tags: php, html, file, text

I am having trouble extracting data from a form. I would like to save email address to a text file to the local server. The user will go firstly to this site (picture),
[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt243.png)

They will type in their email address and a wireless key (controlled by Unifi) and then hit submit. At that point, I would like the email they entered to be saved to a text file. The connect button also authenticates the user with Unifi and they are able to connect to the guest wireless.

The code I have so far is:

```
<!-- Email Input -->
<fieldset class="large-text">
    <p class="form-element">
        <label for="email" class="fieldname">Email</label>
        <input id="emailcontainer" method="post" name="emailtxtbox" class="textInput" value="" autocomplete="on" input type="email" required placeholder="Enter your email"/>
    </p>
</fieldset>
<!-- End of Email Input !-->
```

This creates the email textbox entry that you see above in the picture.

The below code is the php execute, that will (hopefully) grab the email, and then save it too the text file:

```
$getemail = $_GET["emailtxtbox"];
$emailtxtbox = $_POST["emailtxtbox"];

if($getemail = "connect") {
    $targetFolder = "/emailcollate";
    file_put_contents($targetFolder."mytext.txt", $emailtxtbox);
}
```

As you might of guessed, I have no skill in php or html, so please keep it simple. I have played around the above codes a lot, so some of it may have different names etc. I would appreciate any help!

Does anyone think it would be better to use the file_put_contents() function to do the above?

Comment: Have you an html form tag? `<form></form>`

Comment: `$getemail = "connect"` needs `==`

Answer (score 2):

ok, it has been a long time since i have worked with php, but i will do my best.
the way I would troubleshoot this is make sure the php page actually ran, easily done with:

```
    var_dump("this page ran");
```

after the page has run, dump the two variables out to the page to confirm that the page has received them and has accurately change them to a variable.

next, in your if statement, dump some random text to make sure the if statement has run.

otherwise, make sure you know where the php file is trying to save to, may have to use this instead:

```
     file_put_contents("/emailcollate/mytext.txt", $emailtxtbox);
```

the file_put_contents() function should work fine

Answer (score 0):

In PHP `$GET` is used for picking up parameters in your site's URL, and `$POST` is used for gathering form values that are submitted to your page.

In your case you're getting the value for `$getemail` from the URL of your page, so for `$getemail` to have a value the URL for your site should resemble

```
www.yoursite.com/?emailtxtbox=connect
```

Additionally you need to add an extra equals sign in your if statement, like so:

```
if($getemail == "connect") {
```

The double equals is a comparator used for comparing two values against each other, rather than a single equals which is used for assigning a value to a variable.

Your file_put_contents looks ok, but like user6063785 has suggested try running that block of code outside of the if statement to see if the file is being written to. You may need to ensure that PHP has permissions to write to the file.